# Error en Login PHP

Tags: php, mysql, login

Estuve revisando las respuestas similares pero no encontré ninguna parecida.

Aclaro, estoy aprendiendo. Es mi primer código PHP.

Estoy haciendo un login para pasar de una pagina a otra, pero siempre me manda error de usuario , hice un echo de que es lo que se envía y veo que la información esta bien, hice una validación incluso al final o en el error y veo que la información es la correcta, valido que el usuario sea creado correctamente en la tabla en adminmyphp y sin problema lo genera. no se donde esta el error para que no se loguee.

***ya se loguea con la correccion en los 255 caracteres que me recomendo masterguru y me dirige a donde le solicito, pero ahora cuando ingreso un usuario incorrecto se queda en validar.php en blanco.

actualizo los codigos de index.php y validar.php

### Son 4 archivos:

#### 1) insertar.php

```
<?php
include("conexion.php");
$clave_encriptada = password_hash('admin123',PASSWORD_DEFAULT);
$sql = "INSERT INTO tbl_usuarios (nombres, usuario, clave) VALUES ";
$sql .= "('Angel RTR','trea','$clave_encriptada')";

$result = mysqli_query($conn,$sql);
mysqli_close($conn);    
?>
```

#### 2) conexion.php

```
<?php
$host = 'localhost';
$usuario = 'root';
$clave = '';
$basededatos ='login';
$conn = mysqli_connect($host,$usuario,$clave,$basededatos);

if(!$conn) {
    echo "Error al conectarse";
}
?>
```

#### 3) index.php

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <!-- CSS only -->
    <link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.2.0-beta1/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-0evHe/X+R7YkIZDRvuzKMRqM+OrBnVFBL6DOitfPri4tjfHxaWutUpFmBp4vmVor" crossorigin="anonymous">
    <title>Login</title>
</head>
<body>
<div class="p-3 mb-2 bg-secondary top-0" style ="height: 400px;">  
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-3 border mt-3 position-absolute top-50 start-50 translate-middle bg-white">
            <form method="POST" action="validar.php">
                <div class="mb-3">
                <label for="usuario" class="form-label">Usuario</label>
                <input type="text" class="form-control" name="usuario" id="usuario" required placeholder="Ingresa Usuario">
                </div>
                <div class="mb-3">
                <label for="clave" class="form-label">Password</label>
                <input type="password" class="form-control" name="clave" id="clave" required placeholder="Ingresa Contraseña">
                </div>
                <div class="d-grid gap-2 mb-3">
                <button class="btn btn-primary" type="submit" value="Login" name="login">Ingresar</button>
                </div>
            </form>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

#### 4) validar.php

```
<?php

include ('conexion.php');

if (isset($_POST['usuario'])) {
    $usuario = $_POST['usuario'];
    $clave = $_POST['clave'];
    $sql = "SELECT * FROM tbl_usuarios WHERE usuario='$usuario'";
    $result = mysqli_query($conn,$sql);

    if (mysqli_num_rows($result)==1) {
        $fila = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result);
        $clave_db = $fila['clave'];
        if (password_verify($clave,$clave_db)) {
            header ("Location: capturame.php");
        } else {
            header ("Location: index.php");
        }
    }
}
?>
```

[image: Asi esta la tabla en la base]

[image: asi es la composicion de la base]

[image: aqui intento el logueo con un usuario incorrecto]

[image: aqui me dirige]

Comment: ¿Responde esto a tu pregunta? [Login PHP con PDO](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/540044/login-php-con-pdo)

Comment: De cuanto es el campo de la contraseña en la base de datos?  de 255 caracteres o menos?  quizas se ha truncado al almacenarse si es menor de eso

Comment: toda la razon, ya lo cambie a 255 y corrio sin problema. muchas gracias!

Comment: Mira que bien, ale, problema resuelto :- )

Comment: No lo puedo creer... ahora si esta correcto me manda a donde quiero... pero.. si esta mal.. se queda en validar.php

Comment: Bueno, en la pregunta solo has puesto unos echo tanto al validarlo correctamente como si no... en el código que te refieres ahora debe ser distinto y por lo tanto no puedo adivinarlo ni saber que te ocurre

Comment: disculpame @masterguru, ya actualice y di mas detalle .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Diria que no te está entrando en este condicional:

```php
if (mysqli_num_rows($result)==1) {
```

pues si te fijas no tiene su propio **else** después, por lo tanto, al no entrar no devuelve nada y se para allí por falta de más instrucciones, dejando la salida sin contenido (página en blanco).

La solución pasa por poner algo así:

```php
if (mysqli_num_rows($result)==1) {
    $fila = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result);
    $clave_db = $fila['clave'];
    if (password_verify($clave,$clave_db)) {
        header ("Location: capturame.php");
    } else {
        header ("Location: index.php");
    }
} else {
    header ("Location: index.php");
}
```

para redirigir al usuario de nuevo al index.php, del mismo modo que haces cuando la contraseña no es válida. Evidentemente puedes cambiar el index.php por cualquier otra página que desees.