# Login PHP con PDO

Tags: php, mysql

Estoy haciendo mi primer login en PHP con PDO, pero no consigo avanzar. Todo el rato me esta diciendo que el correo/contraseña son incorrectos y no veo donde esta el problema.

Este es mi código PHP para el login. El fallo de inicio de sesión me lo esta dando el ultimo "echo" que tengo puesto. El var dump que tengo justo arriba me muestra la misma contraseña en ambas variables.

```php
<?php
session_start();
require_once('conexion.php');

if (isset($_POST['submit'])) {
 
    $email = $_POST['email'];
    $password = $_POST['password'];
 
    $query = $pdo->prepare("SELECT * FROM users WHERE email=:email");
    $query->bindParam("email", $email, PDO::PARAM_STR);
    $query->execute();
 
    $result = $query->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);

    if (!$result) {
    echo '<p class="error">Usernameeee password combination is wrong!</p>';
    } else {
    if (password_verify($password, $result['password'])) {
        echo '<p class="success">Congratulations, you are logged in!</p>';
    } else {
      var_dump($password, $result['password']);
      die();
        echo '<p class="error">Username password combination is wrong!</p>';
    }
    }
}

?>
```

Ahora mismo esto es lo que me muestra la web al intentar iniciar sesión, la contraseña es "a"

```
MYSQL OK string(1) "a" string(1) "a"
```

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Este es mi código de conexión a mysql:

```
<?php
$dsn = 'mysql:dbname=login;host=localhost';
$user = 'root';
$password = '';
 
try
{
    $pdo = new PDO($dsn,$user,$password);
    $pdo->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
    echo "MYSQL OK";
}
catch(PDOException $e)
{
    echo "PDO error".$e->getMessage();
    die();
}
```

Comment: Nunca, pero **nunca** almacenes contraseñas sin encriptar. Hay países que tienen leyes específicas para eso.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

veo que la base de datos tienes el campo **password** como pleno texto y cuando comparas la contraseña usas la funcion password_verify(). Esta funcion solo funciona si usaste password_hash() cuando guardaste la contrasena y por lo visto no lo hiciste.

Para solucionar tu error, primero puedes encriptar la contrasena con password_hash() o simplemente no usar la funcion password_verify(). asi:

```
<?php
session_start();
require_once('conexion.php');

if (isset($_POST['submit'])) {
 
    $email = $_POST['email'];
    $password = $_POST['password'];
 
    $query = $pdo->prepare("SELECT * FROM users WHERE email=:email");
    $query->bindParam("email", $email, PDO::PARAM_STR);
    $query->execute();
 
    $result = $query->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);

    if (!$result) {
        echo '<p class="error">Usernameeee password combination is wrong!</p>';
    } else {
        //Aqui en el if estaba el error, como usaste password_verify() la contrasena no coincidia
        //hazlo asi
        if ($password == $result['password']) {
            echo '<p class="success">Congratulations, you are logged in!</p>';
        } else {
          var_dump($password, $result['password']);
          die();
            echo '<p class="error">Username password combination is wrong!</p>';
        }
    }
}

?>
```